# Simple php code not printing to screen

Tags: php, echo

This might seem stupid, but I have this simple php code, and it is not echoeing the message to the screen, neither is redirecting the page. I am not sure why. I tested the db connection and it is working, also the user and password used for test exist in the db (of course info changed here for security). What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("C:/webroot/connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //$user=$_POST["httpd_username"];
    $user="usernameXYZ";
    //$pass=$_POST["httpd_password"];
    $pass="passXYZ";

    $query= "SELECT * FROM regtrack_users WHERE user_name='$user' and password='$pass'";
    $result =pg_query($query) or die ("Unable to connect to db");
    $numrows=(pg_num_rows($result));

if($numrows>0){
    $row=pg_fetch_assoc($result);
    $dbuser=$row['user_name'];
    $dbpass=$row['pass'];
    echo "$dbuser and $dbpass";

}


    header("Location:login.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` would be an issue when trying to debug a script. Also `die (error)` is incorrect.

Comment: the php log is not showing any errors. How can I fix this? and why die(error) is wrong? I have used that previously  in other codes and didnt have any problems.

Comment: `error` is a string it should be quoted. With `error_reporting(0)` you are telling the PHP not to report any errors. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: you should really move this on your directory `include_once("C:/webroot/connect.php");` maybe right where your current file is.

Comment: See updated code. I have removed the error_reporting(0). The php log is still not showing any errors. It is like the code is running but it just not displaying the echo on the screen.

Comment: Build your include path using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ---> http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

Comment: In your script, after $numrows is defined and below the if{} block, run ---> die(var_dump($numrows)); ----> probably === 0

Comment: Also, you should always build your scripts to account for the error case or the else condition....this saves you time later. If you had an else block here for the $numrows, and it echoed something like "User not found", you would immediately know the query returned empty, and you would be that much further ahead as your starting point

Comment: Here it is what I found so far. If I remove the "isset['submit']" condition, everything works just fine. But why can I not test if the submit button was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

It might because of this part:

```
if($numrows==1){
    $row=pg_fetch_assoc($result);
    $dbuser=$row['user_name'];
    $dbpass=$row['pass'];
    echo "$dbuser and $dbpass";
}
```

You should check if the $numrows variable really contains 1, or you should try $numrows>0 instead of $numrows==1

Comment: I checked in the db and it does return 1. I have also modified the code to ">1" but the problem continues

Answer (score 0):

Root of the problem lies in 3rd line, you are providing a path to a file to include in wrong way. Read here about how properly you should be providing paths to files in php code:

http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/